# Use grep and get text after the pattern

Tags: linux, grep

I need to get the IP from a log I need to grep the true-client and after that I need to `grep true-client-ip=[191.168.171.15]` and get just the IP

```
2019.02.14-08:26:06:713,asd:1234:chan,0.000,asd,S,request-begin-site,POST,{remoteHost=1.2.3.4,remoteAddr=1.2.3.4,requestType=POST,serverName=api=[text/html],accept-charset=[iso-12345-15, utf-8;q=0.5, *;q=0.5],accept-encoding=[gzip],server-origin=[5],cache-control=[no-cache, max-age=0],pragma=[no-cache],program-header=[true],te=[chunked;q=1.0],true-client-ip=[191.168.171.15],true-host=[www.server.com]
```

I was trying  `grep -o "true-client-ip=[^ ]*,"` but it brings me:

```
true-client-ip=[191.168.171.15],true-host=[www.server.com]
```

I need just `true-client-ip=[191.168.171.15]` so I can cut after to bring get the IP like `true-client-ip=[191.168.171.15] | cut -d= -f2`

Answer (score 1):

Using `grep` `-P` flag if available :

```
grep -oP 'true-client-ip=\[\K[^]]*'
```

Perl's `\K` meta-character discards what precedes when displaying the result, so it will match the "true-client-ip=[" part but only display the IP.

If `grep -P` isn't available, I would use `sed` :

```
sed -nE 's/.*true-client-ip=\[([^]]*).*/\1/p'
```

Comment: Yeah, `\K` is handy :)

Comment: @Tiw sure is, a shame it isn't implemented in more PCRE-based regex engines

Comment: What do you mean by PCRE-based engines? Boost is based on PCRE, and it has `\K` support. Onigmo has `\K` support (Ruby regex engine), but Onigmo is not PCRE based.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I was thinking about languages which implement regex derived from PCRE such as Java and Python, both of which compare their implementation to Perl's but do not implement `\K`. Was my phrasing confusing, or do you think most PCRE-derived regex implementations implement `\K` ?

Comment: They are not based on PCRE, they are quite different. Even from each other. They are compared to Perl regex, because it has been there long before, but not PCRE.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yeah, I guess I meant to say PCRE-derived, I didn't intend to imply the implementation itself was based on Perl's.

Comment: Probably, "Perl-inspired" is a better term here.

Answer (score 1):

If you have GNU grep, you can do it like this:

```
$ grep -oP "(?<=true-client-ip=\[)[^\]]*" file
191.168.171.15
```

The `(?<=)` is called Positive Lookbehind, which you can find related [doc here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).
The backslash `\` in `[^\]]` is actually unnecessary, I just feel like to add it to make it more intuitive, less misleading-prone :-) .

Comment: thank you so much, it works with ...  grep -oP "(?<=true-client-ip=\[)[^\]]*" file